# WPF: Applying a custom theme (skin) to a custom control

Tags: wpf, themes, custom-controls, skinning

I have an application set up so that I can adjust its skin at run time. I am doing it as follows each time I change the skin:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("SomeThemeAssembly;component/Themes/StandardTheme.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
ResourceDictionary resource = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(uri);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resource);
```

This works fine.

I have also created a custom control with its controltemplate defined in Themes/Generic.xaml using ComponentResourceKeys for the relevant resources, etc

```
x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey 
TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:MyCustomControl}, 
ResourceId=MyBrush}"
```

The style of the custom control itself doesnt use a componentresourcekey as I want it to style all instances.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
```

Again this all works fine and standard controls I have used to compose elements of my custom control are appropriately styled when I change the skin.

However there are a number of custom properties( brushes, widths, etc) on my control that need to be styled to fit in with the skins I am applying.

In examples I have seen using the standard windows themes adding an additional file

```
Luna.StandardColor.Xaml
```

for example, to the themes directory of the custom control allows a modified control template to be set and picked up when that particular theme is applied. This won't work for me, as far as I can tell anyway, as my skins are not themes.

Can something similar be achieved when using 'skins' in the manner I have?

Obviously I can add Styles and ControlTemplates to my skin assemblies but this feels wrong especially as there is a standard naming convention across the skin assemblies for resources. So only a single more maintainable style would be required if it could be stored in Themes/StandardTheme.xaml in my custom control's assembly.

Having tried to read around on this subject I have the impression want I want to do is either impossible or will require loads of extra leg work.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: It is hard for me to understand what exactly you are asking. Can you please explain in one or two sentences exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: When I reskin my app at runtime I want the Style for my CustomControl to be different to that in generic.xaml. Similar to if I had changed the theme. The new style should also be in the CustomControls Themes directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CustomControls Themes Directory add a MyNewTheme.xaml file that's a resource dictionary that has an implicit style set for your control. Then merge that resource dictionary in with your other one as needed. For example:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("SomeThemeAssembly;component/Themes/MyNewTheme.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
Uri controlsUri = new Uri("ControlAssembly;component/Themes/MyNewTheme.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
ResourceDictionary resource = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(uri);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resource);
ResourceDictionary resource = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(controlsUri);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resource);
```

Comment: I see, thats a better solution than my fallback. Thanks. 
However if I had 10 CustomControls in different assemblies then the relevant 'changeskin' handler would be pretty bloated. i'm hoping for something a bit more general but if not I will use this approach. Thanks

I do feel a bit of an idiot for not thinking of this as a better fallback. :o)

Comment: If you have 10 CustomControls in different assemblies then what I would do is create a Themes (or Skins) assembly that references these 10 other assemblies. Then in this assembly I would create one Resource dictionary for each theme you are going to use. Have these resource dictionaries merge from the other 10 assemblies. Then your programs only have to interact with this assembly. No matter what if you have 10 CustomControls in different assemblies you are going to have to do a little organizing to deal with ;)

Comment: Good point. Yesterday was a long day!
With fresh eyes this morning I see that what I was trying to do makes little sense anyway. Only my app will know what skins are being applied and how they are structured so any new controltemplates should be organised at that level, in some app specfic resource assembly as you say, not at the custom control level. I just got caught up with the idea of how themes work and assumed there was some magic I was missing. Of course themes are special and limited and thats why it makes sense to include them in the customcontrol assembly. 
Thanks